# solace messaging - not able to connect to solace appliance via nodejs

Tags: node.js, message-queue, messaging, solace-mq, solace

I was trying to connect to solace appliance installed in our organization from `nodejs`. I took the same code as given in solace web messaging demo. As given in the example below are the `session` properties:

```
my_web_server_url = "http://<ip:port>/smf";
my_client_username = "<username>";
my_vpn = "<vpnname>";
my_password = "<password>";
```

When I debug the code of a callback method `solace.SessionEventCBInfo`of `solace.SolclientFactory.createSession`, I found that below condition never meets:

```
if (event.sessionEventCode === solace.SessionEventCode.UP_NOTICE) {
   console.log(":::Connected:::");
}
```

And the control goes to the connecting state for all 3 transport schemes (HTTP_BASIC, HTTP_BASE64 and HTTP_STREAMING) and finally goes to error condition.

```
else if (event.sessionEventCode === solace.SessionEventCode.CONNECTING) {
            console.log(":::Connecting.....");
        } else {
            console.log(":::Error!:::");
        }
```

Is there any configuration issue on solace appliance ? Should web messaging be enabled on solace appliance while configuring ? Or am I doing something wrong in the code ?

**Update**

Please find below the details of `session` event:

```
Session event: sessionEventCode=CONNECTING, infoStr=Establishing connection (transport:HTTP_BINARY_STREAMING), responseCode=, errorSubCode=, correlationKey=, reason=()
(index):105 Connecting.....
(index):102 Session event: sessionEventCode=CONNECTING, infoStr=Establishing connection (transport:HTTP_BINARY), responseCode=, errorSubCode=, correlationKey=, reason=()
(index):105 Connecting.....
(index):102 Session event: sessionEventCode=CONNECTING, infoStr=Establishing connection (transport:HTTP_BASE64), responseCode=, errorSubCode=, correlationKey=, reason=()
(index):105 Connecting.....
(index):102 Session event: sessionEventCode=DISCONNECTED, infoStr=Session is destroyed, responseCode=, errorSubCode=, correlationKey=, reason=(Transport session event: sessionEventCode=2, infoStr=Session is destroyed, responseCode=, sid=)
(index):109 Error!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

The disconnect reason from the API would be able to provide us with more information as to why the connection is failing.

Would you please print out the events right at the start of the session event callback?

```
new solace.SessionEventCBInfo(function(session, event) {
    console.log(event.toString());
    // The rest of your connection logic below
}
```

I would expect to see something similar to the following.

```
Session event: sessionEventCode=CONNECTING, infoStr=Establishing connection (transport:HTTP_BINARY_STREAMING), responseCode=, errorSubCode=, correlationKey=, reason=()
Session event: sessionEventCode=CONNECTING, infoStr=Establishing connection (transport:HTTP_BINARY), responseCode=, errorSubCode=, correlationKey=, reason=()
Session event: sessionEventCode=CONNECTING, infoStr=Establishing connection (transport:HTTP_BASE64), responseCode=, errorSubCode=, correlationKey=, reason=()
Session event: sessionEventCode=DISCONNECTED, infoStr=Connection create failure: HTTP request failed: status=503 statusText=Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH, responseText length=143, XHR errorCode=EHOSTUNREACH, responseCode=, errorSubCode=44, correlationKey=, reason=(Transport session event: sessionEventCode=2, infoStr=Connection create failure: HTTP request failed: status=503 statusText=Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH, responseText length=143, XHR errorCode=EHOSTUNREACH, responseCode=44, sid=N/A)
```

In my example, the Solace appliance cannot be contacted from my server running nodejs. This can be figured out from the EHOSTUNREACH error code.

Do note that the following configuration needs to be done on the Solace Appliance to enable web messaging.

1. A license key needs to be installed on the appliance to enable web messaging. You can verify this via the following command from the CLI.

   ```
   solace1> show product-key

   Product Key : H1mqWPKYjgQ-7JiNX6d2k1M-Tg9Ezd5a7WA-CACHE:WEB:GM450K:OMAMA-C-S009000149
     Unlocked Features : 4
       SolCache
       WEB Transport Service
       Guaranteed Messaging 450k
       OpenMAMA
   ```

   Note that the "WEB Transport Service" is required for web messaging.
2. The Web-Transport service needs to be enabled.

   ```
   solace1> show service

   Msg-Backbone:       Enabled
     SMF:              Enabled
       Web-Transport:  Enabled
     REST Incoming:    Shutdown
     REST Outgoing:    Shutdown

   Max Incoming Connections:       9000
     Service SMF:                  9000
     Service Web-Transport:        9000
     Service REST:                 9000
   Max Outgoing Connections:
     Service REST:                 6000
   Max SSL Connections:            9000
   ```
3. Verify that the port that is used for web transport. The default is 80, and can be verified via the show service command by looking for the WEB service.

   ```
   solace1> show service
       ---- truncated output ----
                                         Status
   Service  VRF   MsgVpn          Port  A O S C R Failed Reason
   -------- ----- --------------- ----- --------- ---------------------------
   SEMP     Mgmt                     80 U U N - -
   SEMP     Mgmt                    443 U D Y - - No Cert
   SMF      MsgBB                 55555 U U N N N
   SMF      MsgBB                 55003 U U N Y N
   SMF      MsgBB                 55556 U D N N Y
   SMF      MsgBB                 55443 U D Y N N No Cert
   WEB      MsgBB                    80 U U - - -
   ```

Comment: I've added the details of event in session callback.

Comment: What version of the nodejs API is being used here? Later versions of the API provide the detailed disconnect information similar to my answer. The latest version of the API is 7.1.0.17 and is backwards compatible with appliances running 6.0 and above. At this point, I would also recommend that you verify the appliance's configuration using the steps outlined in my answer, it is possible that the appliance is not configured for web messaging.